# Add an HTML file in a custom module

Tags: distributions

I have an external application I have to add in my custom feature of Open Atrium. There is some JavaScript files I have already added to the module, and some CSS files.

To implement the application, I need to include an HTML file in the module's output. In which way can I do this?

Comment: Well, you can always do an include_once in your template.

Comment: can include the total html file to the custom module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `<?php print file_get_contents('my_file.html'); ?>` in your module's template file, or even do that inside your module's callback function, and return it as output.

It's a little bit messy, but including off-site files or scripts is always a little messy.